# Сложный MotionLayout в RecyclerView, как реализовать правильно?

Tags: android, xml, анимация, android-constraintlayout

Всем доброго дня.

Стоит следующая **задача**: по нажатию на элемент списка **RecyclerView** в этом элементе появляется новый список (тоже RV) и все остальные элементы **анимированно** сдвигаются вниз.
При этом важно, чтобы этот список находился в **CardView**, который в свою очередь содержит нужный мне **RV**, который при нажатии на **CardView** меняет **visibility** с *gone* на *visible* и при появлении этого списка мой **CardView** растягивался бы на нужную высоту.

На данном этапе я добился того, чтобы мой **CardView** растягивается только до первого элемента списка **RV**, и делает это не плавно, а резко.. Скорее всего проблема кроется в том, что я использую **MotionLayout**, вложенный в другой **MotionLayout**, но я не знаю как по-другому изменять **visibility** моего RV, который находится внутри **CardView** Подскажите, как правильно реализовать данную конструкцию?

[image: изначальное представление моего viewHolder'а]

[image: То, что происходи по нажатию на него]

Вот мой xml с viewHolder'ом, который должен анимироваться:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/day_holder_scene">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/day_view_holder"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/day_holder_xml_constraintlayout3_scene">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_subjects"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/day_tv"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_bold"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_bold"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day_tv"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day_tv" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Вот мои сцены для MotionLayout:

```
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="400">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnClick motion:clickAction="toggle" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>


<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="400">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnClick motion:targetId="@id/day_tv"
            motion:clickAction="toggle" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/recycler_subjects"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/day_tv"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/day_tv"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_subjects"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```